# What are the differences between the various mining picks & drills?

Tags: starbound

The consumable digging implements could vary in the following attributes:

- Power (how many swings to break a block)
- Durability
- Effect size

The size is evident, every pick I've found has a 3x3 size. But I'm not immediately certain how the picks vary in power & durability.

Comment: They definitely differ in power. The effect size and range seems to be identical.  I am not sure about durability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official wiki, Starbounder, currently answers this question on the [Tools](https://starbounder.org/Tools) page.

For convenience, the relevant text is quoted below (2017-10-05, current Starbound version 1.3.2)

> Pickaxes mine blocks in a 3x3 square 10 times per 3 seconds and break
>   after 200 swings, which is about 1 minute of continuous use.
>
> Drills mine blocks in a 2x2 square 10 times per second and break after
>   1000 ticks of damage, which is about 1 minute and 40 seconds of
>   continuous use.
>
> Damage dealt per hit depends only on the material composition of the
>   tool. Copper, silver, gold, platinum and diamond tools deal,
>   respectively, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0 and 3.5 damage per hit.